# Limiting solr spellchecking based on attributes

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I wonder if there is a way to limit the spellchecking to just a part of the index.

Example i have an index containing different products used in different countries.

when a search is performed i limit the solr query to just return the results for COUNTRY X, however the suggestions that are returned are not limited to COUNTRY X, instead i receive results based on the whole index(since i only have one mispell index).

i beleive you can create a separate dictionary one for each country to solve this but here is the twist, i sometimes do a query where i want results back from COUNTRY_X and COUNTRY_Y thus also suggestions limited by those 2 countries, this would in turn result in a dictionary index of its own, seems a little to complicated and the number of dictionary indexes would be large.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try splitting the index per country, i.e. one index for country X and another for country Y. You can easily do this with a [multi-core setup](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin). This way each index gets its own dictionary.

When you want to search on multiple countries at once you run a [distributed query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) over the indexes. Distributed support for the spell checking component is [only available in trunk](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Distributed_Search_Support) as of this writing though.